# Restrict search to specific domains

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using the elasticsearch plugin and I'm running searches using `elasticSearchService.search(myKeywords)` which searches for keywords over all the domain classes marked as `searchable`.

Now I want to restrict the search to two specif domain classes. I can see there are options named `indices` and `types` that can be passed to the search method, but if I simply use my domain class names on them I get errors telling the index or type doesn't exist. What exactly should I do to achieve what I want?

(I'm new to lucene and elasticsearch and I'm not sure I understood the index and type concepts. Reading the docs I could only find examples to restrict searches to an specific field, not a hole domain class or whatever it is mapped to, in lucene/elasticsearch concepts).

Comment: Inspecting `elasticSearchAdminService.indices` I can see one index created for each of my domain classes. The names look like "org.mypackage_v0". Reading the docs I found out that the expected behavior should be one `index` for the hole database and that each domain (table) should be mapped as a `type`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is:

```
elasticSearchService.search(myKeywords, [types:["myPackage.MyClass","myPackage.MyOtherClass"]])
```

The results are as expected, but I'm still worried about having one index (and one type) per domain. Not what I expected but I can't see how to map all domain classes to a single index for the hole database as stated by the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index)

Comment: I understood the plugin creates an index per domains package by default. To create a single index for the application, we must set `elasticSearch.index.name = 'myIndexName'` in Config.groovy